# How to install private repository on Dataflow Worker?

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

We're facing issues during Dataflow jobs deployment.

#### The error

We are using CustomCommands to install private repo on workers, but we face now an error in the `worker-startup` logs of our jobs:

```
Running command: ['pip', 'install', 'git+ssh://git@github.com/my_private_repo.git@v1.0.0']

Command output: b'Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 6, in <module>
from pip._internal import main\nModuleNotFoundError: No module named \'pip\'\n'
```

This code was working but since our last deploy of the service on Friday, it's not.

#### Some context

1. We use a GAE service with a cron job to deploy Dataflow Jobs, using the python sdk
2. In our jobs, we're using code stored in private repository
3. To allow the workers to pull private repositories, we use a `setup.py` with customCommands which are run during worker startup. (code example from official repo [here](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/examples/complete/juliaset/setup.py))
4. The commands retrieve an encoded ssh key from GCS, decode it with KMS, get a ssh config file to specify path of the key & allowed hosts then perform a `pip install git+ssh://git@github.com/my_private_repo.git@v1.0.0` (see commands below)

```html
CUSTOM_COMMANDS = [
 # retrieve ssh key
    ["gsutil", "cp","gs://{bucket_name}/encrypted_python_repo_ssh_key".format(bucket_name=credentials_bucket), "encrypted_key"],
    [
        "gcloud",
        "kms",
        "decrypt",
        "--location",
        "global",
        "--keyring",
        project,
        "--key",
        project,
        "--plaintext-file",
        "decrypted_key",
        "--ciphertext-file",
        "encrypted_key",
    ],
    ["chmod", "700", "decrypted_key"],
    
    # install git & ssh
    ["apt-get", "update"],
    ["apt-get", "install", "-y", "openssh-server"],
    ["apt-get", "install", "-y", "git"],

    # Add ssh config which specify the location of the key & the host
    [
        "gsutil",
        "cp",
        "gs://{bucket_name}/ssh_config_gcloud".format(bucket_name=credentials_bucket),
        "~/.ssh/config",
    ],
    [
        "pip",
        "install",
        "git+ssh://git@github.com/my_private_repo.git@v1.0.0",
    ],
]
```

#### What we tried

- Following this issue in pip [#5599](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599), it seems that there is a conflict between several versions of pip. 
  We tried to reinstall it adding `apt-get --reinstall install -y python-setuptools python-wheel python-pip` (and other variations like `curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py && python3 get-pip.py --force-reinstall`) in the CustomCommands but no specific improvement.

#### To Note:

- Jobs started locally are working (How ? I'm quite curious how can it work since the CustomCommands are not run)
- Logging in the compute instance & connect to the docker process & running the commands manually doesn't show any error log
- Service is deployed using a custom Dockerfile defined by following snippet

```html
FROM gcr.io/google-appengine/python
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y openssh-server
RUN virtualenv /env -p python3.7

# Setting these environment variables are the same as running
# source /env/bin/activate.
ENV VIRTUAL_ENV /env
ENV PATH /env/bin:$PATH

# Set credentials for git run pip to install all
# dependencies into the virtualenv.
... specify SSH KEY, host, to allow private git repo pull 

# Add the application source code.
ADD . /app
RUN pip install -r /app/requirements.txt && python /app/setup.py install && python /app/setup.py build
CMD gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app
```

Any idea about how to solve this issue, or any workaround available ?

Thanks for your help !

#### Edit

This seems mostly due to local state of the machine, or our computers.

After running some commands like `python setup.py install` or `python setup.py build`, I'm now unable to deploy jobs anymore (facing the same error during `worker-startup` as deployed by the service), but my colleague is still able to deploy jobs (same code, same branch, except excluded directories from .gitignore like `build`, `dist`, ...) which are running. In his case, CustomCommands are not run on job deployment (but workers are still able to use local packaged pipeline).

Any way to specify a compiled package to use by worker ? I was not able to find doc on that...

#### Workaround

As we were not able to pull private code from dataflow worker, we used the following workaround:

- Build a wheel of our private repo using `python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel`
- Embed this wheel in our dataflow package under `lib/my-package-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl`
- Pass the wheel to dataflow options as extra package (see beam code [here](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/options/pipeline_options.py#L879))

Commands used

```
pipeline_options = PipelineOptions()
pipeline_options.view_as(SetupOptions).setup_file = "./setup.py"
pipeline_options.view_as(SetupOptions).extra_packages = ["./lib/my-package-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl"]
```

Comment: What version of apache beam are you using and was this upgraded recently?

Comment: Apache beam 2.16 (last version until this week) and no, no recent changes.

Comment: Also, can you check the python version of the application triggering the dataflow job from GAE ?

Comment: While connecting through ssh to the docker image running the gunicorn server, I get:
- Python version: Python 3.7.2
- While doing pip freeze, I got `apache-beam==2.16.0` and relevant dependancies (including my private package)
Note: the service is deployed through a DockerFile I've added to my post

Comment: Can you change your pip to pip3 and try running ?

Comment: We ever tried that, including some other combinations and we got the same error...
- ['pip', 'install', 'git+ssh://git@github.com/my_private_repo.git@v1.0.0']
- ['pip3', 'install', 'git+ssh://git@github.com/my_private_repo.git@v1.0.0']
- ['python', '-m', 'pip', 'install', 'git+ssh://git@github.com/my_private_repo.git@v1.0.0']
- ['python3', '-m', 'pip3', 'install', 'git+ssh://git@github.com/my_private_repo.git@v1.0.0']

Comment: Can you add these to the custom commands `curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
python3 get-pip.py --force-reinstall` and then run a pip3 install ? It seems to me that the python version is 3.x and custom command is running pip which is for 2.x

Comment: We tried that but we had some conflicts. Errors in customCommands while running the `python3 get-pip.py --force-reinstall` command: For each of our setup.py dependencies, we have this kind of error `ERROR: dataflow-python-pipeline 2.0.1 requires apache-beam[gcp]==2.16.0, which is not installed.\nERROR: dataflow-python-pipeline 2.0.1 requires cachetools<4,>=3.1.1, which is not installed...`.  Then same error as previously for the `pip3 install git+ssh://git@github.com/my_private_repo.git@v1.0.0` command

Answer (score 2):

For anything but non-trivial, public dependencies I would recommend using [custom containers](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/using-custom-containers) and installing all the dependencies ahead of time.